# How to create Event on facebook through iphone app

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

I want to create event on facebook in my app. I am using FBGraph Api.

Here is the code:

```
NSString *strGetProfil=[NSString stringWithFormat:
                       @"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/events?access_token=%@&name=%@&start_time=%@&end_time=%@&description=%@&location=%@&location_id=
                       %@&privacy_type=%@",[getAllInfo objectAtIndex:4],[getAllInfo objectAtIndex:7],@"teing",@"2010-03-14T14:00:00",@"2010-03-14T17:30:00",@"",@"",@"",@""];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strGetProfil];
```

Please guide me for right path.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @PauldeLange I am not able to create event. Actually i dnt know which method is used for that. If you know please guide me.

Comment: @PauldeLange I am using the api mentioned above in code. But I am not getting TRUE in result. So how can i get the True value in result.

Comment: You can start by reading [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) on Events and looking at the [SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/) samples.